# How to insert result of this nested array to SQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //var_dump($_POST);
}

function formatForm($form, $level)
{
    $sqli = "INSERT INTO reservation_tour_line (prefix, Dept_ID, Quantity,  
    Memo, User_ID, Date_Time) ";
    foreach ($form as $key => $value) {
        if ($level == -1) {
            //echo "\nForm $key\n";
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if ($level > -1) {
                //echo str_repeat("\t", $level);
                //echo "$key\n";
            }
            formatForm($value, $level + 1);
        } else {
            if ($level > -1) {
                //echo str_repeat("\t", $level);
            }
            echo "$key : $value\n";
        }
    }
}

formatForm($_POST, -1);
?>
```

the result from script above is like this..

```
bookers_prefix : Mr 
bookers_firstname : Bryan 
lastname : Steve 
bbtcno : 
bookers_birthdays : 07/08/1988 
bookers_phone : 
bookers_email : bryan@gmail.com 
bookers_mobilephone : 0123456789 
bookers_address : COOLPLACE 
additional_name : test 
additional_curr : USD additional_price : 250
```

what i want achieve is something like this :

```
INSERT INTO reservation_tour_line (prefix, Dept_ID, Quantity, Memo, User_ID, Date_Time)VALUES('Mr','Bryan',..., '250')
```

in other words, i need to combine the result into one query insert to insert that value to sql.

Any solution will be appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Your code is very dangerous and could potentially lead to SQL injections, especially given that you're apparently using the contents of $_POST without any validation.  I'd recommend you look into learning to use prepared statements, and that you also do some validation of your input before letting it get to the query stage.

Comment: thanks for good suggestion. i'll do it after i find the way to create query insert first...